# Google Search Console errors (nofollow?)

Tags: google-search, web-crawlers

I have a web site where some internal links take you to another pages of the same site, passing some parameters.
Eg.:

```
<a href="/BookMgm/PreparePayment?quantity=1&itemId=123">Book</a>
```

My issue is **I don't want crawlers follows these links**.

I know I must not use the "nofollows" rel for internal links, so I tried with robots.txt:

```
User-agent: * 
Disallow: /backoffice/
Disallow: /bookmgm/
```

Unfortunatelly I continue to receive google search console errors like:

```
Server errors:
https://portamiinpista.it/BookMgm/PreparePaymentForm?quantity=1&itemId=10811
```

Comment: URLs are case sensitive.  Does your URL actually have capital letters in it?  Because your robots.txt does not.

Comment: Even if you prevent Googlebot from crawling these URLs in the future, you may see reports of server errors from the URLs it has already crawled for months.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller, I was not aware robots.txt is case-sensitive. I just fixed it. Let's see what happen.